# How to POST request using axios with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my Signupcomponent

```
const SignupComponent = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        username: 'silvio1',
        name: 'Silvioo',
        email: 'berlusconi@gmail.com',
        password: '123ooo007',
    });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { username, name, email, password } = values;
        const user = {username, name, email, password};

        await axios.post('${API)/signup', user);        
    };

    const handleChange = name => e => {
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const showLoading = () => (loading ? <div className="alert alert-info">Loading...</div> : '');

    const signupForm = () => {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        value={values.username}
                        onChange={handleChange('username')}
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Type your username"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        value={values.name}
                        onChange={handleChange('name')}
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Type your name"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        value={values.email}
                        onChange={handleChange('email')}
                        type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Type your email"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        value={values.password}
                        onChange={handleChange('password')}
                        type="password"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Type your password"
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Signup</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    };

    return <React.Fragment>
        {showLoading()}
        {signupForm()} 
         </React.Fragment>;
};

export default SignupComponent;
```

EDIT
I changed my code(zhulien's accepted answer).
Signup page appears,I try to sign up user.
I got error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Request failed with status code 404

Call Stack
createError
node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js (16:0)
settle
node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js (17:0)
XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad
node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js (62:0)
```

Frontend folder

```
components
config.js
next.config.js
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
pages
```

My pages folder

```
_document.js
index.js
signin.js
signup.js
```

signup.js imports the code above

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import SignupComponent from '../components/frontauth/SignupComponent';

const Signup = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h2>Signup page</h2>
            <SignupComponent />
        </Layout>
    );
};
```

My next.config.js

```
{
  APP_NAME: 'BLOG FRONTEND',
  APP_DEVELOPMENT: 'http://localhost:3000',
  PRODUCTION: false
}
```

And config.js

```
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

console.log(publicRuntimeConfig);
export const API = publicRuntimeConfig.PRODUCTION
    ? 'https://cryptoblog.com'
    : 'http://localhost:3000';
export const APP_NAME = publicRuntimeConfig.APP_NAME;
```

I am new to React and React Hooks. How to solve this problem?

Comment: `username` is a property on your state object, you probably want to use `value={values.username}`

Comment: call username from values states such as values.username

Comment: dont know if it's related to your error or not but who puts an useEffect inside a function ??seems like you wanted the useEffect to trigger when component renders for the first time,but that wont happen actually.

Comment: @Sakshi How? Can you post an answer?

Comment: @Sakshi Yes,exactly I want trigger when component renders.

Comment: @RichardRublev Can you post the contents of the 'API', please? By 'API' I mean the variable that you're using to construct the URL located at '../../config'. I suppose it is just a string. Seems like you're either trying to post to an invalid URL or the server is not responding properly.

Comment: @zhulien Added my config.

Comment: @RichardRublev You're using '${API)/signup' to construct the URL for the POST request. First, you're TRYING to use string interpolation but you're actually not. You have to wrap it like that \`${API)/signup\`. Mind the difference between ' and `. Second I am still not sure what is the value of the API variable. Can you post the whole content of the file, please?
Talking about this line => import { API } from '../../config';

Comment: @zhulien I should avoid string interpolation?

Comment: @RichardRublev No, no. You should use it. The problem is that you're trying to use an interpolated variable in non-interpolated string. See my comment above, I've edited it as it was automatically formatted without the \` sign.

Comment: @zhulien Thanks,yes I see my error now.

Comment: @zhulien Works perfect now!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you're trying to access `{username}`(which doesn't exist) instead of the state property which is `values.username`. Furthermore, don't use hooks in event handlers, they should be used in the top level body of the component or in custom hooks only. Checkout this: [React hooks rules](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks).

So:

1. In your form you have to use the state(`values`) properties.
2. Extract `useEffect` hook in the main body flow of the component or **BETTER remove it altogether as you're not using it properly currently. You're better of with just the simple event handler for form submit which should post the data somewhere without setting any state.**

Your code could look something like:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { API } from '../../config';

const SignupComponent = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        username: 'silvio1',
        name: 'Silvioo',
        email: 'berlusconi@gmail.com',
        password: '123ooo007',
    });

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { username, name, email, password } = values;
        const user = {username, name, email, password};

        await axios.post('${API)/signup', user);        
    };

    const handleChange = name => e => {
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const showLoading = () => (loading ? <div className="alert alert-info">Loading...</div> : '');

    const signupForm = () => {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        value={values.username}
                        onChange={handleChange('username')}
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Type your username"
                    />
                </div>
```

Comment: Can't you also remove `async` from handleSubmit as `await axios.post('${API)/signup', user);` can be changed to be just `axios.post('${API)/signup'` in this particular case (as there are no dependent values after the `.post()`) ?

Comment: @NickParsons If he is not using the loader, he can. However, I put it there as he might want to update the loading state to false after the operation has completed.

Comment: Nice, makes sense (nice answer btw!)

Answer (score 1):

this is how it should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
            postUser();
          }, []);
```

not inside the function the way you have done it:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setValues({...values});
        const { username, name, email, password } = values;
        const user = {username, name, email, password};
        
        async function postUser () {
            const result = await axios.post('${API)/signup', user);
        };

          useEffect(() => {
            postUser();
          }, []);

    };
```

UseEffects aren't meant to be placed inside your functions.Just place them inside your functional component,with some value(or no value) inside your dependency array of the useEffect.These values present inside the array will trigger the useEffect whenever they get changed.